# Does memory allocated on the stack get cleared out when freed?

Tags: c++, c, memory

If we allocate memory on the stack like so:

```
void foobar()
{
    int arr[10];
}
```

After `foobar()` exits, the reference to this memory block (`arr`) is lost. But is it zeroed out?

Comment: _"But is it set to zero?"_ no

Comment: It actually doesn't matter, because any attempt to access that memory is Undefined Behaviour, causing your program to be simply incorrect and capable of doing literally anything

Comment: How could a conforming program tell whether it was or not?

Comment: Those are two different questions. Most stack memory (and, for that matter, most memory in general) is not going to be automatically zeroed when it's freed. On the other hand, the memory from that array is *freed*, in the sense that it's free for the stack to use for other variables and data in the future. But to answer the question I think you're asking, no you don't have to worry about freeing it by hand.

Comment: General rule of Thumb: C++ doesn't spend time doing stuff you don't explicitly ask for.

Comment: "If we allocate memory on the stack" - I don't personally consider changing the `SP` register to be "allocating" memory. A thread's stack is pre-allocated/reserved by the OS when the thread is created (assuming x86/AMD64)

Comment: If you're wondering because `arr` might contain sensitive data and you want it to be overwritten, this is outside the scope of standard C/C++ and you'd have to look to your implementation's documentation.  But I don't know any common implementations that do so, other than maybe with special debugging flags or instrumentation.

Comment: On the DS9K, the memory does not get cleared, but does have its *electrified* status bit set, so any read or write access to that memory will charge the keyboard and mouse and likely kill the user (if grounded).

Comment: Too high tech, @Eljay I prefer the reliability of an army of Ninjas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But is it set to zero?

No / maybe. There are no guarantees about the "value" of unallocated memory. Nor is there any way guaranteed by the standard to observe that hypothetical "value".

From an information security perspective: If you store private information in an object, then you should assume that the information may persist even after the storage duration of the object. And that an attacker may be able to access that information if your program is vulnerable to an exploit (typically, through undefined behaviour).

Comment: Note: `memset()` is not a good way to clear memory just prior to return.  It may be optimized out.

Comment: Hmmm, casting target to `volatile unsigned char *` and using a loop works fairly well.  But details of that are another question - and likely a dupe.  IAC, I like the security concerns this answer begins.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Hmm, I didn't think of `volatile`. I'm not sure if even that is safe in precence of UB, but technically it's supposed to guarantee "writes".

Answer (score 2):

No, the value is not set to zero. But you shouldn't even bother with it as the value is inaccessible. It will probably have the value of what was there before the end of the function, but accessing it will be [Undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

The reason why value will probably be there is because the program will just move its stack pointer. Next time stack gets to that address it will just rewrite it with value that it needs.